# Trying to get a random number from db php doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
    $total_numMIN = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MIN(id) FROM view_rating");
    $total_numMAX = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(id) FROM view_rating");
     $random_no = mt_rand($total_numMIN, $total_numMAX);    
     print $random_no;
```

I'm trying to get a single number randomly generated from the smallest and largest numbers in my database. Right now the error I'm getting is

> Warning: mt_rand() expects parameter 1 to be integer, object given in

I'm just not exactly sure why the results of the queries aren't integers

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Warning: mt_rand() expects parameter 1 to be integer, object given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` returns a `mysqli_result` which is an object and not the numbers you are expecting. You need to get an array of results from your query. The MIN and MAX queries can also be combined into a single query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MIN(id) as min, MAX(id) as max FROM view_rating");

if($result) {
    $resultArray = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $random_no = mt_rand($resultArray['min'], $resultArray['max']);    
    print $random_no;
}
```

There may be a cleaner way to do this. I haven't used PHP in a long time.

Comment: I think you should give the columns aliases, so they have more reasonable names.

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this

```
$total_numMIN = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MIN(id) as min,MAX(id) as max FROM view_rating"));
$random_no = mt_rand($total_numMIN['min'], $total_numMAX['max']);    
print $random_no;
```

because mysqli_query just give you a object. you have to fetch data as an associative array and then you can use it into mt_rand
hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_query returns a result - and not a value.

From the documentation on the function: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.